# How to use rel="alternate" hreflang in a multilingual site

Tags: html, seo

We have `website.com/en/content1` for English and the same content on `website.com/de/content1` in German.

My issue is that I need to use `rel="alternate"` hreflang for all the urls like above on my whole site. And as I am new to SEO so I need to know how and where I can implement it

Comment: Read this [Link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

As your website is also available in German, you may want to look at this:
[www.ranking-check.de/blog/hreflang-die-5-haeufigsten-fehler-und-hall-of-fame/](https://www.ranking-check.de/blog/hreflang-die-5-haeufigsten-fehler-und-hall-of-fame/)

But it's really not that complicated. Just add a link-element for each language to the head-section of your page.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://website.com/de/content1" hreflang="de"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://website.com/en/content1" hreflang="en"/>
```

Only problem is, that the href-attribute has to be adapted for each page. Ideally the pages are created dynamically by some scripting language with a single starting point (for example anything is redirected to index.php). Then you only have to change 1 file, as you can build the URL following your routing.

If you offer links to switch language (flags), add the hreflang-attribute there too.